# Is this bad programming?

Tags: c#, .net

Is this bad programming ?

```
DateTime dtExpire = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(90);
while (client.Connected && DateTime.Now < dtExpire)
{
    if (client.Available == 0) continue;
    //or can also use: if (!networkStream.DataAvailable) continue;

    dtExpire = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30);

    //now do stuff with client via stream
}
```

The goal being to insure that the client does not take too mor time than the server is willing to wait to pocess incoming messages. Of course, this code is inside of a Try/Catch block, as well as a Using Stream block, so the server would gracefully handle dropped connections or any other socket exceptions.

Basically, I just want to know if there's a better way to handle this. Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with TCP, except some vague network operations that are irrelevant to the actual question. Please retag propertly, starting with the language you're using here (c#?)

Comment: this might be better for code review

Comment: Please edit the question's title. It is too generic...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `ReceiveTimeout` property to specify how long to wait for an incoming message. When you use the `Receive` method (or its family of methods) and a timeout occurs, a `SocketException` will be thrown.

```
client.ReceiveTimeout = 90;
```

Your code will be more complex if you have to accomplish this asynchronously, but it doesn't look like you are. `Receive` by itself should do the job as it will block on the current thread.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for; I've added the ReceiveTimeout.

Answer (score 1):

This is called [busy waiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting).

You are essentially clogging the CPU even when there is no "real" work to be done (i.e. when you are just waiting on `client.Available` to become different from 0). Fortunately, your busy waiting has a timeout so at least it won't clog the CPU forever.

Whether you can do it more efficiently really only depends on what the `client` is and whether it implements a more efficient waiting strategy.

If it doesn't then you'll be stuck with some form of busy waiting, but not all is lost - if you can tolerate a slight delay in detecting the change in `client.Available`, then doing...

```
if (client.Available == 0) {
   Thread.Sleep(max_delay_you_can_tolerate);
   continue;
}
```

...would go a long way taking the pressure off the CPU.

**--- EDIT ---**

If `client` is in fact a `Socket`, take a look at `Blocking` and `ReceiveTimeout` properties.